# MySQL Query Counting Rows and Returning the Row with the Most Occurances

Tags: php, mysql, database

Heres my issue.

I have a db for a radio station that I've cobbled together.

Currently, I'm using a php script to query the mysql db and insert rows via a post, another one returns the last played song, and the other one shows the last 10 songs.

I've got 48k rows with ID Artist Title Date and Time from the last 3 months.

What I'm trying to do, unsuccessfully so far, is to create a script to query the DB count the rows with each title and then return one of the rows that contains the title that appears most desc to least.

I want to return 40 rows of most played songs.

I have no issues returning the last played song, but I am lost on where to start with the query.

To complicate things, I have a break row being entered at every commercial break, so thats causing the top played song to be break. lol.

Finally, how can I cache this data to be updated every hour, so that everytime the page is loaded I'm not making a large query.

I'd appreciate some help with this. And also where is a good place to learn more advance queries like this. I'm just now getting in to this level.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select Artist, Title, count(*) as PlayCount
from MyTable
where Title <> 'Break'
group by Artist, Title
order by count(*) desc
limit 0, 40
```